# How to make gtab drawings in songs package bigger?

Tags: formatting, songs

I'm using the [songs](http://songs.sourceforge.net/) package to write a songbook. It also includes the `gtab` command that creates a chord diagram.

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[chorded,nomeasures,noshading]{songs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    textwidth=18cm,
    left=15mm,
    top=20mm
}

\begin{document}

\section{Title for comparison}

\gtab{}{1:X01234:004321} \gtab{}{2:X01234:004321} \gtab{}{3:X01234:004321} \gtab{}{4:X01234:004321}
\gtab{}{5:X01234:004321} \gtab{}{6:X01234:004321} \gtab{}{7:X01234:004321} \gtab{}{8:X01234:004321}
\gtab{}{9:X01234:004321} \gtab{}{10:X01234:004321} \gtab{}{11:X01234:004321} \gtab{}{12:X01234:004321}

\end{document}
```

It produces the following result:

[image]

As you can see, the resulting diagrams are really small (eleven of them can be fitted in a line). How to make them `x`-times as big, for a user defined `x > 1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `graphicx`s `\scalebox` macro. The following example doubles the size of `\gtab`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[chorded,nomeasures,noshading]{songs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    textwidth=18cm,
    left=15mm,
    top=20mm
}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\let\gtabBAK\gtab
\newcommand{\sgtab}[3]{\scalebox{#1}{\gtabBAK{#2}{#3}}}
\renewcommand*\gtab{\sgtab{2}}


\begin{document}

\section{Title for comparison}

\gtab{}{1:X01234:004321} \gtab{}{2:X01234:004321} \gtab{}{3:X01234:004321} \gtab{}{4:X01234:004321}
\gtab{}{5:X01234:004321} \gtab{}{6:X01234:004321} \gtab{}{7:X01234:004321} \gtab{}{8:X01234:004321}
\gtab{}{9:X01234:004321} \gtab{}{10:X01234:004321} \gtab{}{11:X01234:004321} \gtab{}{12:X01234:004321}

\end{document}
```